# Intersection of sets: $\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}} \left[ -\frac{1}{n}, 0 \right[$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Why is the following true?$$\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}} \left[ -\frac{1}{n}, 0 \right[ = \emptyset$$
The sets which are intersected get "smaller", and as $n \rightarrow \infty$, I reasoned that the interval becomes $[0,0[$. I don't exactly know how to make sense of that, but why not let this intersection be the set $\{0\}$ instead of an empty set? I understand that $[-1/n,0[$ does **not** contain zero, but $[0,0[$ seems to contain and not contain (?) zero.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the meaning of $[a,b[$?

Comment: Because $0 \notin [-1/n, 0[$ for any $n.$

Comment: If anyone else is wondering, our friend Sherheryar means $[a,b) = [a,b[.$ This notation is commonly used in Europe more than in the NA.

Comment: It is the set $\{x \in \mathbb{R} | a \leq x < b \}$

Comment: @SheheryarZaidi So $\;[0,0[ \;=\; \{x \in \mathbb R | 0 \le x \;\land\; x \lt 0\} \;=\; \{x \in \mathbb R | \text{false}\} \;=\; \emptyset\;$.  So it does not contain $\;0\;$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that set was not empty. Then, there would be $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x\geq\frac{-1}{n}$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, but $x<0$. Can you show why there is no such x?

Comment: Well, if I choose a certain $x \in \mathbb{R}$, which is non zero and negative, then I can always find some $n$ for which $-1/n > x$. Good argument. Similar to DanUznanski's.

Answer (score 1):

You've got the hard part but not the easy here.  It does become $\left[0,0\right[$; but this is obviously the empty interval.  $\left[x,x\right]$ is merely $\left\{x\right\}$, but $\left[x,x\right[$ is *open* on the right, and so the set can't contain $x$ either.  Since that's the only thing in the set already, there's nothing left.

Comment: Well, the right side of $[x,x[$ says that $x$ is not part of the interval but the left side says $x$ **is** part of the interval. Why go for the right side and not the left?

Comment: Think about it.  $[0,0[ = \{x \in \mathbb{R} : 0 \leq x < 0\}$.  What element is simultaneously greater than or equal to $0$ and less than $0$?

Comment: @SheheryarZaidi, if one element does not belong in one set, it won't belong in the intersection of all those sets.

Comment: There is no such element, I agree with that then! +1

Answer (score 1):

The question looks interesting, the primary purpose is to dissect the following method!

Say $x\in[-1/n,0)$

Now for any $x$ (negative) which belong to any of the above  the set, we can always find a $n_1\in Z^+$, such that $x<-1/n_1$. Hence there can't be any number which satisfies the above condition!

Answer (score 0):

$
\newcommand{\calc}{\begin{align}\quad &}
\newcommand{\calcop}[2]{\\ #1\quad &\quad\text{"#2"}\\\quad & }
\newcommand{\endcalc}{\end{align}}
$Here is how I would prove this, directly using the definitions.  Implicitly letting $\;n \in \mathbb Z ^+\;$, we calculate the elements $\;x\;$ of this set:

$$\calc
x \in \langle \cap n :: \left[ -1/n, 0 \right[ \rangle
\calcop{\equiv}{definition of $\;\cap\;$}
\langle \forall n :: x \in \left[ -1/n, 0 \right[ \rangle
\calcop{\equiv}{definition of $\;[\cdot,\cdot[\;$}
\langle \forall n :: -1/n \leq x \lt 0 \rangle
\calcop{\equiv}{logic: move part not using $\;n\;$ out of $\;\forall n\;$; arithmetic: multiply by $\;n\;$}
\langle \forall n :: -1 \leq x \times n \rangle \;\land\; x \lt 0
\calcop{\equiv}{arithmetic: divide by $\;x\;$, allowed with changing sign by $\;x \lt 0\;$}
\langle \forall n :: -1/x \geq n \rangle \;\land\; x \lt 0
\calcop{\equiv}{arithmetic: $\;\langle \forall n :: y \geq n \rangle\;$ is false}
\text{false}
\endcalc$$