# Finding the limit of sets

Tags: limits

I have a problem, where I have difficulties with solving these two exercises.
Here is the problem 
If $C_1$, $C_2$ ... are sets where $C_k \supset C_{k+1}$, where k=1,2,3. Then the limit of $C_k$, where $k \to \infty$ is defined as the intersection between the sets, I have to find the limit, where $k \to \infty$ of $C_k$.

The first problem is
$C_k = \{x: 2-1/k < x \leq 2 \}$

and the second problem is
$C_k= \{x:2<x \leq 2+1/k \}$

where k for both cases are k=1,2,3,4....

Can someone tell me the difference between these two exercises, since the exercises in my eyes will end up with the empty set.

Comment: Is your question really 'what is the difference between these two exercises'?

Comment: I have difficulties with solving these two exercises, since I end up with the empty set for both exercises, while the solution for the first problem is 2 and the empty set for the other problem. I cannot understand why we say the solution is {2} for the first problem.

Comment: So the solution to the first one say $\bigcap \limits_{k=1}^{+\infty} \left(C_k\right)=\{2\}$. This is a set equality. Can you prove any of the inclusions?

Comment: Don't you mean intersection instead? Can't I just solve the problem by looking at the inequalities? Or am I totally wrong?

Comment: I meant intersection. I edited my comment. Just by looking one might guess the answer (and one might guess wrongly), whether you require a proof or not is something that depends on you/your lecturer/your audience, etc.

Comment: I still don't understand how the solution is 2. Can you come with a detailed explanation?

Comment: I can, but it would be better if you did yourself. Start by answering the question I asked in my second comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16981/discussion-between-aa-x-and-git-gud).

Comment: @GitGud: These would end up in the empty set, wouldn't they? Why $2$?

Comment: @SheheryarZaidi If you deny $\bigcap \limits_{k=1}^{+\infty} \left(C_k\right)=\{2\}$, if not both, which inclusion would fail?

Comment: Sorry, I misread. I do agree with you. See my answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

The first part is the following: $$ \bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty} \left( 2-\frac{1}{k}, 2 \right]$$ Now as $k \rightarrow \infty$ we are left with an $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x \leq 2$ but also $x > 2 - 1/k$ for any $k$, which can clearly be 2.

The second part is the following: $$ \bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty} \left( 2, 2 + \frac{1}{k} \right]$$ which means that as $k \rightarrow \infty$ we get a real number $x$ that satisfies the conditions $x > 2$ and also $x \leq 2+1/k$ for **any** $k$. Now notice that we can't let $x=2$ due to the first condition, so it has to be slightly bigger than 2 (say 2.001 for the sake of argument), but we can always let $k$ become larger enough so that $2+1/k$ becomes smaller than our chosen $x$. For example put $k=10000$ and then $2.001$ would be too big.

So basically there is no such $x$ which can satisfy the condition meaning that the answer is the empty set.

Comment: Also, see this question which I asked yesterday, it's almost the same question: [Intersection of sets](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/921664/intersection-of-sets-bigcap-n-in-mathbbz-left-frac1n-0-ri)